# returning a PDF on the fly using NextJS 9

Tags: express, pdf, webpack, next.js

I'm trying to figure out how to send a pdf that was dynamically created to the client from the nextjs 9 api. I'm not sure if this is a nextjs error, a file pathing error or a webpack error. Guidance would be great.

filepath = /pages/api/pdf.js

```
var fs = require('fs')
export default function handle(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body) // The request body
    console.log(req.query) // The url querystring
    console.log(req.cookies) // The passed cookies
        var stream = fs.createReadStream(destinationPDF);
        var filename = "filled.pdf"; 
        // Be careful of special characters

        filename = encodeURIComponent(filename);
        // Ideally this should strip them

        res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'inline; filename="' + filename + '"');
        res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');

        stream.pipe(res);

}
```

The error
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   ../../public/static/85.pdf
resolves to localhost:3000/static/85.pdf

Error of concern:

```
 let data = _babel_runtime_corejs2_core_js_object_assign__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default()(fdfData, fieldNames);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's currently not possible to read files from API routes or pages.

https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/8334